# Printf ubuntu Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, printf

I have this code:

```
int a;
printf("&a = %u\n",(unsigned)&a);
printf("a\n");
printf("b\n");
printf("c\n");
printf("d\n");
```

I tried to print the pointer of `a` variable.
But it fail on the row `printf("a\n");` and says `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
Output:

```
&a = 134525024
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I remove the row `printf("&a = %u\n",(unsigned)&a);` from the code, its success.
Output:

```
a
b
c
d
```

What worng in my code?

Comment: Is it your whole source code?

Comment: Nothing wrong in what you've shown.

Comment: Use `%p` to print pointer value, instead of `%u`.

Comment: @Rohan It's cast to `unsigned`, so `%u` is correct (though `%p` and a cast to `void*` would be more informative).

Comment: I tried to print int value to with %d, but this error shown again. It happened when I try to print value with %...

Comment: @Someone: Paste your whole source code ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: @DanielFischer according to the standard that's legal but it doesn't seem to be correct: "_Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type."_

Comment: @Kirilenko - That's the whole code, it is my main function.

Comment: @Someone: Even with `int main (void) { int a; printf("%p\n", (void *)a); return 0; }`, it fails?

Comment: No, but if I will put another `printf` after this printf the new one will fail. Is there any option that my `make` command wrong?

Comment: Did you `#include <stdio.h>`?  Did you add `-Wall` to your compilation options (or, what happens when you do)?  You'd do best with also including `#include <inttypes.h>` and using `printf("%a = 0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)&a);` as (on all systems where `uintptr_t` is defined) the result is guaranteed not to truncate any digits (whereas casting to `int`, `unsigned`, `long`, `unsigned long`, even `unsigned long long` is not guaranteed to do so).  That is a C99 header, but it's in Linux OK.

Comment: I just don't understand it! Its not working for me! I added `-Wall` option, and tried to use `inttypes.h`, and it still do not work!!
BUT if i write the SAME code on C complier in windows, its works just fine! That is realy weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solvd my problem. I just reinstall my ubuntu and the vmware, now its work. I am not realy sure what the exact problem, but it solved my problem... :-)

Answer (score 0):

This could be an architecture problem. I ran this on OS X and it ran fine:

```
#import <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("&a = %u\n",(unsigned int)&a);
    printf("a\n");
    printf("b\n");
    printf("c\n");
    printf("d\n");
}
```

However, I did get a warning during compilation:

```
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
```

I am on a 64-bit machine, so my 64-bit pointers can't fit into a 32-bit int.
Try running this instead and see what you get:

```
#import <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("unsigned %ld\n", sizeof(unsigned)); // sizes reported in bytes
    printf("int %ld\n", sizeof(int));           // same as unsigned
    printf("long %ld\n", sizeof(long));         // should fit a pointer
    printf("ptr %ld\n", sizeof(void*));         // size of a pointer
    printf("&a = %lu\n", (unsigned long)&a);    // should print out your pointer
    printf("&a = %p\n", &a);                    // the Right Way of doing things
}
```

Output:

```
unsigned 4
int 4
long 8
ptr 8
&a = 140734544742408
&a = 0x7fff508c0808
```

EDIT:

Just in case you didn't know, `unsigned` actually means `unsigned int`. Likewise, `long` actually means `long int`.

Also, whether a value is `signed` or `unsigned` does not change its physical size, only how it is interpreted. You can see that from the first 2 prints.

Comment: Its also not working for me... I use vmware to simulate ubuntu

Comment: Are you getting any compile warnings? `gcc -o test test.c`

Comment: Yes, my compiler understands that directive. Sorry for stepping outside C. `#import` is roughly the same as `#include` with [include guards built in](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/cpp/Obsolete-once-only-headers.html). At any rate, if it was a problem, it would be a compile time problem.

Comment: #import is Objective-C.